# VBA - Find duplicate and compare which one of them is the highest

Tags: vba, excel

Hey I'm trying to filter/match my sheet for duplicates and i have two criterias:

1. Look for duplicates anywhere in `(column B)`, if there are duplicates set "Applicable" in `(column E)` on the same rows as the found duplicates.
2. The one of the duplicates in `(column B)` that has the highest number in  `(column C)` (number between 0-10) should still have "Applicable" in `(column E)` but the lowest number should get "Removed" in `(column E)` instead. I want i to look like this:

[image]

```
Sub FindDUB()
    Dim lastRow As Long 'Declaring the lastRow variable

    Dim MatchReqprodID As Long 'store the match index values of the given value
    Dim MatchRevision As Double 'store the match index values of the given value

    Dim RevisionColumnCompare As Integer 'Column number in sheet
    Dim ReqprodIDColumnCompare As Integer 'Column number in sheet

    Dim CompareReqprodID As Long 'Compare is to loop through all the records in the column using For loop
    Dim CompareRevision As Long 'Compare is to loop through all the records in the column using For loop

    RevisionColumnCompare = 3 'C
    ReqprodIDColumnCompare = 2 'B

    'Finding the last row in Reqprod ID
    lastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    'looping through the Reqprod ID column
    For CompareReqprodID = 1 To lastRow



        If Cells(CompareReqprodID, ReqprodIDColumnCompare) <> "" Then 'skipping if it is blank.

            'getting match index number for the value of the cell
            MatchReqprodID = WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(CompareReqprodID, ReqprodIDColumnCompare), Range("B1:B" & lastRow), 0)
            'MatchRevision = Application.WorksheetFunction.Large(RevisionColumnCompare, 1)

            'if the match index is not equals to current row number, then it is a duplicate value
            If CompareReqprodID <> MatchReqprodID Then
                'If CompareRevision <> MatchRevision Then
                   ' Cells(CompareReqprodID, ApplicableColumn) = "Removed"
                   ' Cells(MatchReqprodID, ApplicableColumn) = "Applicable"
                'Else
                    Cells(CompareReqprodID, ApplicableColumn) = "Applicable"
                    Cells(MatchReqprodID, ApplicableColumn) = "Removed"
                'End If

            End If

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

This code is not stable and it does not work now, It worked before if `MatchRevision` and `If CompareRevision <> MatchRevision Then` function is removed. Then i could find the duplicates but not indicate which one of them  that has the highest revision.

So my question is if it´s how can i filter through my sheet, find the duplicates and see which of the duplicates that has the highest "Revision" value of the two and set the highest to "Applicable" and the lowest to "Removed" in "Status". Thanks!

Comment: You can use a formula for this.

Comment: can you not have more than two instances of "Reqprod ID" in your dataset?

Comment: You don't appear to define `ApplicableColumn` in the VBA you posted, if I run this with the value set to 5 then it sort of works.  I also had to switch around the bit where you set "Applicable" or "Removed" as I think this was also back to front.

Comment: The same "Reqprod ID" can appear more then twice, this i just a snip from my dataset. So for instance ID "34" can appear 2-5 times. @Shazu

Comment: Sorry, `ApplicableColumn` is defined somewhere else in the code and it should be 5 yes. For me the oder of the "Applicable" and "Removed" was right, but the order actually dose not matter since i need to sort with the highest value depending on what number "Revision" has and that´s what i cant figur out by my self... Thanks for trying @RichardHansell

Comment: where do you assign value to the variable CompareRevision?

Comment: For now nowhere... Before i hade a dubbel with for loop´s, first `For CompareReqprodID = 1 To lastRow` and then right under `For  CompareRevision = 1 To lastRow` and the ide was to compare both Revision and RegprodID, but that did not work. So that is now a un used variabel. @Shazu

Comment: What type of formula? @SJR

Comment: I edited the code to as it was before... The edited code can now find duplicates in my sheet add random "Applicable" or "Removed" to the found duplicates, but it can´t  look if its a high or low value i Revision

Comment: Can you not use `MatchRevision = CInt(Cells(MatchReqprodID, RevisionColumnCompare).Value)` and `CompareRevision = CInt(Cells(CompareReqprodID, RevisionColumnCompare).Value)`, then your `<>` on the comparison below would become `<` and the `Else` statement now makes sense.  Note this is on your pre-edited code base.

Comment: I'll post something later if nobody else does.

Comment: I ran this and the only other change I needed was to skip the header, as it doesn't have numeric in it, so `For CompareReqprodID = 2 To lastRow`.  But note that this only works if there are 1 or 2 versions of each product.  if there are 3 or more then it tags all but the lowest with "Applicable".

Comment: @sesar post an example of a “before” and “after” scenario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub FindDUB()

    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim currentRow As Long
    Dim innerRow As Long
    Dim frequency As Integer
    Dim currentID As Long
    Dim currentValue As Long
    Dim firstValue As Long

    lastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For currentRow = 1 To lastRow
        frequency = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B:B"), Range("B" & currentRow).Value)
        If frequency > 1 Then
            Range("E" & currentRow).Value = "Removed"
        Else
        End If
    Next currentRow

    For currentRow = 1 To lastRow
        If Range("E" & currentRow).Value = "Removed" Or Range("E" & currentRow).Value = "Applicable" Then

            currentID = CLng(Range("B" & currentRow).Value)
            firstValue = CLng(Range("C" & currentRow).Value)

            For innerRow = currentRow To lastRow
                If CLng(Range("B" & innerRow).Value) = currentID Then
                    If CLng(Range("C" & innerRow).Value) < firstValue Then
                        Range("E" & currentRow).Value = "Applicable"
                        Range("E" & innerRow).Value = "Removed"
                    ElseIf CLng(Range("C" & innerRow).Value) > firstValue Then
                        Range("E" & currentRow).Value = "Removed"
                        Range("E" & innerRow).Value = "Applicable"
                    Else
                    End If
                Else
                End If
            Next innerRow

        Else
        End If

    Next currentRow


End Sub
```

Comment: replace "Tabelle1" with the name of your worksheet :)

Comment: Thanks you! This works almost, except that i get an overflow error at `currentID = CInt(Range("B" & currentRow).Value)`

Comment: oh sorry. Then let's try to change ints to longs. See updated code please

Comment: There is sadly still an overflow at the same currentID :)

Comment: what is the value in that particular cell?

Comment: "Range("B" & currentRow).Value =382697" so it quite high

Comment: from my knowledge a Long can hold much more than that, so i don´t know why its an overflow

Comment: indeed. I am also flabbergasted.

Comment: did you change the declarations as well? please copy paste my code again, or make sure, that you declare currentID As Long

Comment: I removed CInt to make the firstValue compare with only the range and it worked! :)

Comment: Thank you o much for the help! really!

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to do this using a formula then you could do the following, but note that this is very manual in nature.

First I created some sample data as follows:

```
A    B          C           D
     ReqProdId  Revision    Owner
     12         2           sis
     34         4           sis
     38         1           hbv
     12         3           sis
     12         4           sis
     34         9           sis
     37         4           hbv
```

So Column A has nothing in it, Column B is your Product Id, Column C is your revision number and Column D is the owner.  Your actual data starts at row number 2.

I then added column headers for E = Status, F = Max and G = Min.

The formula for column F, that you type into Cell F2 is `=MAX(IF(B:B=B2,C:C))`, but you have to hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter to add this formula.

The formula for Column G, that you type into Cell G2 is `=MIN(IF(B:B=B2,C:C))`, but again this needs to be entered with Ctrl-Shift-Enter to make it work properly.

Drag the formulae for Columns F and G down to the end of your data, and they should populate with the lowest/ highest revision numbers per group.

From this we can finally add the formula to fill in the Status column, which goes into cell E2 as `=IF(F2=G2, "", IF(C2=G2,"Removed",IF(C2=F2,"Applicable","")))`.  This formula can be entered as normal, with a simple Enter.  It then also needs copying down to the end of your data table.

So the logic (in case it isn't already clear) is as follows:

- Determine the minimum revision number for each group;
- Determine the maximum revision number for each group;
- If the minimum and maximum numbers are the same then there are no duplicates, so set the status to blank;
- If the current revision number matches the minimum number then this is the lowest in the set so set the status to "Removed";
- If the current revision number matches the maximum number then this is the highest in the set so set the status to "Applicable";
- In all other cases this is in between the maximum and minimum number for the group, so set the status to blank.

I did this as a test and it worked fine, but the manual copying of formulae isn't ideal.

---

Forgot to add my results:

```
A    B          C           D        E           F      G
     ReqProdId  Revision    Owner    Status      Max    Min
     12         2           sis      Removed     4      2
     34         4           sis      Removed     9      4
     38         1           hbv                  1      1
     12         3           sis                  4      2
     12         4           sis      Applicable  4      2
     34         9           sis      Applicable  9      4
     37         4           hbv                  4      4
```

Comment: It's probably also worth pointing out that this is *not* your sample data, as I wanted to have an "in between" value, and some rows with no duplicates.

Comment: You could make it a single cell formula, and avoid extra columns!

Comment: Yes, it *could* be a single cell formula, but it would be a horribly long formula, so I left it as it is to show how it works.  Obviously if this was used for real then it would be fine to have a nasty formula, so it would make more sense.

Comment: But just for completeness, this is the CSE (ctrl-shift-enter) formula for doing it all in a single cell, it isn't actually as bad as I thought it would be `=IF(MAX(IF(B:B=B2,C:C))=MIN(IF(B:B=B2,C:C)), "", IF(C2=MIN(IF(B:B=B2,C:C)),"Lowest",IF(C2=MAX(IF(B:B=B2,C:C)),"Highest","")))`

Comment: I would just do `{=IF(COUNTIF(B:B;B3)>1;IF(C3=MAX(IF(B:B=B3;C:C));"Applicable";"Removed");"")}`

Comment: I don't see why you wouldn't need MIN, as the OP wants to tag both the highest and lowest numbers in each group.

Comment: Right... TL;DR :-) Good answer!

Comment: @LS_DEV I tried your formula and it sort of worked, but it marked my "in between" case (the row that starts 12, 3) as "Applicable" when I think this should be "".  If the data set only ever contains 1 or 2 cases per product then your solution would indeed be superior.  I guess it depends on how the actual data looks...?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Dictionary lib.

You need to add the reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" (Tools -> References)

```
sub FindDUB()

    dim row, lastRow, firstRow, Id as Long

    dim checkedId as Dictionary

    Dim ApplicableColumn As Integer 'Column number in sheet
    Dim RevisionColumnCompare As Integer 'Column number in sheet
    Dim ReqprodIDColumnCompare As Integer 'Column number in sheet

    ApplicableColumn = 5 'E
    RevisionColumnCompare = 3 'C
    ReqprodIDColumnCompare = 2 'B

    set checkedId = new Dictionary

    firstRow = 'SET HERE THE FIRST ROW OF DATA RANGE IN YOUR COLUMN
    lastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    for row = firstRow to lastRow

        id = Cells(row,ReqprodIDColumnCompare).value

        if checkedId.exists(id) then

           'Don't know if you want to compare also EQUALS cells, change as you want it.
            if Cells(checkedId(id),RevisionColumnCompare).value < Cells(row,RevisionColumnCompare).value

            Cells(checkedId(id),ApplicableColumn).value = "Removed"

            checkedId(id).value = row

        else

            checkedId.add id, row

        end if

    next

    dim key

    for each key in checkedId.keys

        Cells(checkedId(key),ApplicableColumn).value = "Applicable"

    next

end sub
```

Comment: This is one of the fastest ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this array formula will do it (use Ctrl, Shift and Enter and the curly brackets will appear as in Richard's answer).

```
=IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$7,B2)>1,IF(C2=MAX(IF($B$2:$B$7=B2,$C$2:$C$7)),"Applicable","Removed"),"")
```

[image]